# Masking Log Output Value for Dynamic File Name in Logback XML

Tags: xml, jenkins-plugins, logback, karate

I have a value I need masked in log output that is used to generate the Cucumber Reports for my Jenkins jobs.  The only way this seems to be possible is modifying the logback.xml file for the repo.

I've tried:

```
<appender name="REPORT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    <file>target/surefire-reports/*.html</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %replace(%msg){'(?&lt;=api-key:).*', 'xxxx'}%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

But I get an incorrect filename error:

```
16:58:44,485 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[REPORT] - openFile(target/surefire-reports/*.html,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\surefire-reports\*.html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\surefire-reports\*.html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course as soon as I ask, I figure it out...

`<pattern>%-5level - %replace(%msg){'(?&lt;=api-key:).*', 'xxxx'}%n</pattern>`

Output:
`1 > api-key:xxxx`

Got the format from logback documentation:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#cwOptions
`<pattern>%-5level - %replace(%msg){'\d{14,16}', 'XXXX'}%n</pattern>`

And the regex is the one I'm using to mask Jenkins log output, replacing the left angle bracket with html `&lt;` due to it being in an xml file.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that's on the roadmap: https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-22529225

For now, you could try running a brute-force regex replace on all `*.json` files (and also delete the `*.xml` files) in the `target/surefire-reports` folder. Make sure you do this *before* the routine to generate the cucumber-html-reports is run.

Comment: Was able to implement by adding the masking in the runner file, so:
jsonPaths.forEach(path -> {
                    Path fullPath = Paths.get(path);
                    try {
                        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(fullPath), charset);
                        content = content.replaceAll("(api-key: )(\\w*)", "api-key: masked");
                        Files.write(fullPath, content.getBytes(charset));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        )
;

Comment: @anutter thank you ! I updated this issue with details to help others, feel free to add: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/699#issuecomment-505779697