# Karate api testing - I would like to mask param values

Tags: karate

I would like to mask maven input param values in karate logs

**Steps**

When param user = karate.properties['UserName']

When param password = karate.properties['password']

**Maven command**

mvn clean test ......... -DUserName=user1 -Dpassword=123456

**logs**

When we called method get it prints total url so it's printing user and password as well but I would like to mask those values.

Ex - GET http://......&user=user1&password=123456

Expected output log - GET http://......&user=user1&password=XXXXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this issue for multiple solutions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/699#issuecomment-506078717

in `logback.xml`:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %replace(%msg){'(?&lt;=api-key:).*', ' xxxx'}%n</pattern>
```

Also note that you can omit steps from the log: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

Comment: Sorry for late ask, these mask functionality is not working for HTML reports - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745485/143475 - Can you please let me know where exactly I have to use this code

Comment: @chandrashekar I have nothing to add beyond the links above. you can assume that some of what you want is not supported yet, it is on the roadmap